# Ubuntu 12.04 Laptop Heating problem

Tags: 12.04, cpu, overheating, temperature

I have dual booted Windows 8 with Ubuntu 12.04.
When I use Windows the temperature remains normal but when i use Ubuntu my laptop gets heated up and the temperature goes to 70-90 degrees C just after 5 minutes and remains above 70 degrees after that.
I have tried lots of things but nothing worked. I installed Jupiter, tried disabling the graphis but don't know why it's not getting disabled.
Is there any solution?

> rittik@dell:~$ sensors
>   coretemp-isa-0000
>   Adapter: ISA adapter
>   Physical id 0:  +84.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
>   Core 0:         +80.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
>   Core 1:         +84.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

Answer (score 0):

Is it just overheating, or are you experiencing power consumption problems as well? You could try and limit the CPU frequency at which your box operates by using a nifty little program called "cpu-freq", works great on my Dell running Ubuntu 14.10.

Link to info (basically doubled my battery life)
http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/how-to-improve-laptop-power-management.html

Comment: battery works for 2 to 2 and half hrs so it drains in less time than usual and can you please elaborate on what you are telling about nifty?

Comment: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/how-to-improve-laptop-power-management.html (site helped me out a lot when I was first setting up my box)

Comment: If this did help, let me know, I love helping out other members of this community, plus I need a decent rep score to tackle some of the bigger questions posted here. :D enjoy!

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: hmmm. you installed the software via the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

## Use [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc) to control your fan

I use an Acer Aspire E5-573G nothing else worked to control the CPU fan, but [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/First-steps). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The exact profile for my model is missing, but nbfc worked fine with another similar profile (Acer Aspire E5-575G). If you don't know which profile to use, you can try:
`mono nbfc.exe config -r`

Also I edit the default profile to turn the fan policy more aggressive.

## Build it on Ubuntu

You need the latest mono version, so update it, as required:

```
sudo apt remove mono-complete
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mono-complete
```

Clone the git repository, build

```
# git is needed, so install it
sudo apt install git

# clone the repository into /tmp/nbfc
git clone https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc.git /tmp/nbfc
cd /tmp/nbfc

# Build NBFC
./build.sh

# After the build, "install" nbfc as properly
sudo mkdir /opt/nbfc
sudo cp -r /tmp/nbfc/Linux/bin/Release /opt/nbfc/
sudo cp /tmp/nbfc/Linux/{nbfc.service,nbfc-sleep.service} /etc/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl enable nbfc --now

# Now you need to discover a profile for your machine .
# All profiles are into /opt/nbfc/Configs as XML files
cd /opt/nbfc

# Run the following to discover a similar profile to your machine
mono nbfc.exe config -r

# Use one profile from the suggest list the previous command  
mono nbfc.exe config --apply "Config file name without extension"

# Now start the service
mono nbfc.exe start

# To show what is happen with your fan/machine, run
mono nbfc.exe status --all
```

The nbfc project wiki is very rich and well documented. Take a look if you have some doubt.
Good luck.

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to spam the same answer to so many questions, even if the answer might be useful.

Comment: Sorry, @MerlijnSebrechts. I just think it can help a lot of people with the same problem. I tried everything and nothing else worked.